# Using one Button to scroll down and to top, depending on scroll value

Tags: jquery, html, button, scroll

Im trying to use only one button to both scroll down when scrollTop is less than 250, and scroll back to top when scroll is heigher than 250.

The system that i came up with works fine when scrolling down, but gets stuck for a while before scrolling back to the top:

Css:

```
.rotate{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 1.5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12), 0 -1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.24);
}
.totop{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 15%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1.5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.24);
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.totop i{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #757575;
}
```

Html:

```
<a class="totop ripple" data-ripple-color="#89669b" href="#"><i class="material-icons">arrow_downward</i></a>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.totop').removeClass("rotate");
$(".totop").click(function(event){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '+=300px'}, 800);
});

$(document).scroll(function() {
var y = $(document).scrollTop();
if (y > 250) {
        $('.totop').addClass("rotate");
        $(".totop").click(function(event){
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0'}, 800);
        });
      } else if (y <= 250){
        $('.totop').removeClass("rotate");
        $(".totop").click(function(event){
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '+=600px'}, 800);
        });
      }    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a working solution separating the class toggle and onclick event:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(document).scrollTop();
  if (y > 250) {
      $('.totop').addClass("rotate");
  } else if (y <= 250){
      $('.totop').removeClass("rotate");
  }
});

$(".totop").click(function(event){
    var y = $(document).scrollTop();
    var down = y+600;
        if($(this).hasClass('rotate')) {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0'}, 800);
    } else {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: down}, 800);
    }
});
```

fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vbt7ypqq/

Comment: Thanks mate, appreciate it